# windows batch copy * but omit a single folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

How can I copy all files/folders in a directory using a batch file but omit one? I know I could always delete it after the fact but it is an extremely large folder and I don't want to waste the time copying it. There are numerous files in the location I want to copy so doing it one individually would be unrealistic. Thank yoU!

Comment: Did you read the help files for `XCOPY` and `ROBOCOPY`?

Answer (score 0):

```
robocopy "source" "destination" files_to_copy.ext /e /xd "folder_to_exclude"
```

`robocopy` is an upgraded version of `xcopy`, thus, is more useful. You can check the complete usage by typing `robocopy /?`, [or from the microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy), or from [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

EDIT: Almost forgot, robocopy accepts wildcards, so you can type `*.*` to copy every files. The line I suggest already have the option `/e`, which will copy all subfolders, even the empty ones. `/xf:file_to_exclude.ext` can also be used to skip a specific file type, eg. `/xf:"*.txt"` to exclude all the .txt files.

`xf` is used to exclude files, `xd` to exclude folders.